# SSH Tunnel within docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, mqtt

I have a client running in a docker container that subscribes to a MQTT broker and then writes the data into a database. 
To connect to the MQTT Broker i will have to set up port forwarding.

While developing the client on my local machine the following worked fine:

```
SSH -L <mqtt-port:1883>:localhost:<9000> <user>@<ip-of-server-running-broker>
```

The client is then configured to subscribe to the MQTT broker via localhost:9000.
This all works fine on my local machine.

Within the container it wont, unless I run the container with `--net=host` but I'd rather not do that due to security concerns.

I tried the following:

1. Create docker network "testNetwork"
2. Run a ssh_tunnel container within "testNetwork" and implement port forwarding inside this container.
3. Run the database_client container within "testNetwork" and subscribe to the mqtt broker via the bridge network like ("ssh_tunnel.testNetwork:")

(I want 2 seperate containers for this because the ip address will have to be altered quite often and I don't want to re-build the client container all the time)

But all of my attempts have failed so far. The forwarding seems to work (I can access the shell on the server in the ssh container) but I haven't found a way to actually subscribe to the mqtt broker from within the client container.

Maybe this is actually quite simple and I just don't see how it works, but I've been stuck on this problem for hours by now...
Any help or hints are appreciated!

Comment: I'd configure the client running the Docker container to use host `host.docker.internal`. Not sure though if it's equal to using `--net=host`...

Comment: How did you verify that Step 2 was correctly performed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was actually quite simple and works without using `-net=host`.
I needed to bind to `0.0.0.0` and use the Gateway Forwarding Option  to allow remote hosts (the database client) to connect to the forwarded ports.

`ssh -g -L *:<hostport>:localhost:<mqtt-port/remote port> <user>@<remote-ip>`

Other containers within the same Docker bridge network can then simply use the connection string `<name-of-ssh-container>:<hostport>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for posting it, finally could make it work! Small correction though, the `-g` shouldn't be between `-L` and the forwarding options

Comment: @dain Glad my solution was useful to you!  I don't really see the need for the correction though, the command works exactly as I intended. Could you elaborate?

Comment: If I left the order like that, I got `Bad local forwarding specification '-g'` which makes sense as the `-g` is inserted between `-L` and its parameters

Comment: Weird. The order works for me .. What operating system are you on?

Comment: `OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019` and 
`Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)`

Comment: I got the same error as @dain, change `-L -g ...` to `-g -L ...` fixed it for me. Thanks for the solution though!